# inet_pton with all zero ip address

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am using inet_pton  to verify if the input IP address is valid and is not all zeros ( 0.0.0.0 or 00.00.0.0).

```
inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst)
```

If the input ip (src) address is 0.0.0.0 inet_pton set dst to value 0.  If src value is 00.00.00.00 , dst value is not 0, but I get a random value for each trail.  Why inet_pton convert 0.00.00.00 to value 0

```
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int s;
    struct in_addr ipvalue;

    printf("converting %s to network address \n", argv[1]);
    s = inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &ipvalue);

    if(s < 0)
            printf("inet_pton conversion error \n");

    printf("converted value = %x \n", ipvalue.s_addr);
}
```

**Sample Runs**

Correct values:

```
./a.out 10.1.2.3
converting 10.1.2.3 to network address
converted value = 302010a
```

```
./a.out 0.0.0.0
converting 0.0.0.0 to network address
converted value = 0
```

Incorrect results:

```
./a.out 00.00.00.0
converting 00.00.00.0 to network address
converted value = **a58396a0**
```

```
./a.out 00.0.0.0
converting 00.0.0.0 to network address
converted value = **919e2c30**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not checking if `inet_pton()` returns 0. The [man page of inet_pton](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) states:

> inet_pton() returns 1 on success (network address was successfully
>   converted).  0 is returned if src does not contain a character string
>   representing a valid network address in the specified address family.
>   If af does not contain a valid address family, -1 is returned and
>   errno is set to EAFNOSUPPORT

Try something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int s;
    struct in_addr ipvalue;

    printf("converting %s to network address \n", argv[1]);
    s = inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &ipvalue);

    switch(s) {
       case 1:
          printf("converted value = %x \n", ipvalue.s_addr);
          return 0;
       case 0:
          printf("invalid input: %s\n", argv[1]);
          return 1;
       default:
          printf("inet_pton conversion error \n");
          return 1;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt read the documentation.

`man inet_pton` on my Linux box tells me that your error return check is wrong. It returns 1 on success. Anything else is an error. 0 means an invalid conversion. -1 means an invalid address family.